# I have problem about nested loop by python/html

Tags: python, html, html-lists

I have just started learning Flask and Python. I have problems when I  recieve value and show result from nested loop

HTML:

```
{% for item in text %}
{% for sc in abc %}
<ul>{{item}}</ul>
<ul>
    {% for list_sc in sc %}
    <li>{{ list_sc }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

python:

```
text = ['1','2']
b = [ ['a','b','c'],
     ['D','E','F']]
return render_template('index.html',text = text,abc = b)
```

I want out put is 
output:

1

- a
- b
- c

2

- D
- E
- F

But I having :

1

- a
- b
- c

1

- D
- E
- F

2

- a
- b
- c

2

- D
- E
- F

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a difficult task. But by taking inspiration from [the official doc of Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#loop-controls) (which provides a lot of built-in functions, including loop controls), here is my code that solves your problem:

```
{% for item in text %}
    {% for sc in abc %}

        {% if loop.index0 == 0 %}
            {% if item == '1' %}
                <ul>{{item}}</ul>

                <ul>
                    {% for list_sc in sc %}
                        <li>{{ list_sc }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if loop.index0 == 1 %}
            {% if item == '2' %}
                <ul>{{item}}</ul>

                <ul>
                    {% for list_sc in sc %} 
                        <li>{{ list_sc }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>

            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can see that I'm using the **loop.index0** function, which returns the current iteration of the loop starting with index 0. This allows me to extract only the data from the first sub-list in the first case, or those from the second sub-list in my second condition.